# MySQL COUNT on multiple relations

Tags: mysql, database, join, count

I am trying to figure out how to return the counts of multiple different items in seperate tables related to the table i am joining too.

Im quite new to joins so im not sure if im using correct join. hopefully you can help me!

the tables would be like this:

staff_type table

```
id        type
1         doctor
2         nurse
3         surgeon
```

staff table

```
id        type_id        name
1         1              bob
2         1              jane
3         2              phil
4         2              esther
5         3              michael jackson
```

im tring to construct a statement that will return me the COUNT off the various different staff types, as in how many dactors, how many nurses etc. I also want the query to bring the data from the staff_type table.

I haven't much ideas on how to construct this query, but it may look something like this:

```
SELECT staff_type.*, COUNT(Staff.type_id = staff_type.id)
INNER JOIN staff AS Staff ON (staff_type.id = Staff.type_id)
```

i know this is nothing like what its supposed to be, bit hopefully some of you can point me in the right direction. Other posts on this topic are hard for me to understand and look like they are trying to do something slightly different.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this as an example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , COUNT(s.id) AS count_staff
  FROM staff_type t
  LEFT
  JOIN staff s
    ON s.type_id = t.id
 GROUP
    BY t.id
     , t.name
```

To understand what that's doing, you can remove the `GROUP BY` and the aggregate expression (`COUNT`) function in the `SELECT` list, and see the rows returned by the JOIN operation.

For example:

```
SELECT t.id      AS `t.id`
     , t.name    AS `t.name`
     , s.id      AS `s.id`
     , s.name    AS `s.name`
     , s.type_id AS `s.type_id`
  FROM staff_type t
  LEFT
  JOIN staff s
    ON s.type_id = t.id
 ORDER
    BY t.id
     , s.id
```

Note that the `LEFT` keyword indicates an "outer join". This is going to return all the rows from the table on the left side, even if there aren't any matching rows on the right side. (This will let us get a "zero" count for a `staff_type` that doesn't have any related staff.)

When we add the `GROUP BY` clause, that says to "collapse" all the rows that have the same values for the expressions or columns in the `GROUP BY` list.

We can use an *aggregate* function, such as `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()` to perform an operation on all of the rows that are collapsed into a group.

The `COUNT()` aggregate starts at zero, and increments by one for every non-NULL value. So, we use an expression, `COUNT(s.id)` that we are guaranteed will be non-NULL if there is a matching row from staff, and will be NULL if there isn't a matching row.

(I hope this helps clear up some of your confusion.)

Comment: For seeing the "outer join" in operation, add a new row to `staff_type` that doesn't have any corresponding rows in `staff`, and you should get a zero count for that `staff_type`. Remove the `LEFT` keyword to make it an "inner join", and that `staff_type` won't appear in the resultset. Either way is fine, it depends what result you want to return. But the example you give looks a lot like a case where the users might want to see zero counts... if the specification is like "list all staff_type along with the number of staff of each type"

Comment: thanks very much for your help kind sir, this worked like a charm! my understanding of the differences between joins is quite little but your post will help me grasp it better, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The query will be,

```
select staff_type.*, count(staff.id) as count  from staff_type left join staff on (staff.type_id = staff_type.id) group by staff_type.id
```